# highcharts map bubble with categorized classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

With highcharts, is it possible to make a "Map bubble" (https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-bubble) by adding an analysis in class like on the "Tile map circles" (https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/circlemap-africa)?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you well. Would you like to add the colorAxis to the map-bubble chart, like it is done here? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wsahz93c/

Comment: Yes ! This is what I was looking for ! Do you know how I could add a legend for the bubbles size ? I was thinking of using this :
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.bubbleLegend

Comment: Yes, I do. You need to add the `highcharts-more module script` to your document. `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>` Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nr1y47a9/

Comment: That's perfect ! If you answer, I can accept your solution ! Best regards !

Comment: Sure I will, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The functionality which you are looking for is a **colorAxis**.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wsahz93c/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis

- To use the **bubbleLegend** feature the **highcharts-more** module is required.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nr1y47a9/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/legend.bubbleLegend

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {

  $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    var data1 = data.slice(0, 70),
      data2 = data.slice(70, 150),
      data3 = data.slice(150);

    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
      chart: {
        borderWidth: 1
      },

      title: {
        text: 'World population 2010 by country'
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: 'Map bubble color demo'
      },

      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },

      mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'Countries',
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        color: '#E0E0E0',
        enableMouseTracking: false
      }, {
        type: 'mapbubble',
        color: '#ff0000',
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
        data: data1,
        name: 'Population 2010',

        minSize: 4,
        maxSize: '12%',
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
        }
      }, {
        type: 'mapbubble',
        color: '#00ff00',
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
        data: data2,
        name: 'Population 2010',

        minSize: 4,
        maxSize: '12%',
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
        }
      }, {
        type: 'mapbubble',
        color: '#0000ff',
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
        data: data3,
        name: 'Population 2010',

        minSize: 4,
        maxSize: '12%',
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
        }
      }]
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Taher for your answer ! I'm gonna test this. Do you know how I could add a legend for the bubbles size (not just color) ? I was thinking of using this : api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.bubbleLegend

Comment: I think this will help you.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/bubble-legend/bordercolor/)